# NoSuchMethodError when running sf:deploy from Heroku

Tags: ant

I'm trying to deploy via the Force.com migration tool from a Heroku server. My project includes v35.0 of ant-salesforce.jar. But when the app launches the build, I get an error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
>   com.sforce.soap.metadata.DeployOptions.setTestLevel(Lcom/sforce/soap/metadata/TestLevel;)

I'm not explicitly setting the test level. Wouldn't the "deploy" and "setTestLevel" methods be in the same jar? If not, what are ant-salesforce's dependencies? Any hints on debugging?

Comment: Turns out I had a mismatch in API versions between ant-salesforce.jar and another component. Moving to API version 31.0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download ant salesforce.jar file which is required for the deployment and salesforce version is affecting only when you move the different versions of apex classes.[image]

Please let me know if any deployment related questions.